# Reading particular columns of Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I need to read particular columns from an Excel sheet (say Columns A,P,Q,B) and also some particular cells (say C3 or D10). I do not need it to be displayed in a DataGrid view or anything (all examples I have seen use DataGrid).

How do I do that and write them into a new CSV file?

I have no sample code as I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: I'd recommend EPPlus open excel package. Have a look here http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you use the ExcelReaderInterop library.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Detailed example can be found here:
 http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

I had to deal with a similar issue a few weeks ago and could not find a simpler way to deal with this. The post suggest this overkill approach may be due to lots of legacy code in the library.

Comment: It is a real pain to work with Office Interop.  EPPlus is a far better solution for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully used the Microsoft Access Database engine to open and read Excel files.  The "2010 Access Redistributable" can also be installed on a server free of charge.  What you asking for is a multi-step process:

1. Open a connection to the file using the Access OleDbConnection.  In the connection string the "Data Source" is the file name.
2. Select the appropriate worksheet, which will return a DataTable object.
3. Grab a row from the data table or iterate over top of all of them myDataTable.Rows.
4. Access the column in question.

This post shows some of the process:

- [SSIS Excel Source Connection. What does it use to read Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486409/ssis-excel-source-connection-what-does-it-use-to-read-excel)

Hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the columns that I needed to another excel sheet and saved it as CSV. Then read this csv to perform the task.

This was the easiest option as the machine I was suppose to run the program didn't have Microsoft office.